# How to fix incompatible string to int error?

Tags: java

I am getting a error for incompatible string and int. How do I fix the error?
Here is what I am trying to get. getSongByTitle(title:String):int a method that takes the song title as input and returns as output the position of the song in the list. If not found, the  method returns -1.

```
public int getSongByTitle(String title){
    if (title == this.songList.length){
        return this.songList[title];
    }
    else if (title != this.songList.length){
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `title == this.songList.length` You cannot compare String to an int.

Comment: By deleting wrong code and writing correct code. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off with the songList being a list rather than array, this will mean you can easily add and remove songs from it and will give you the utility function indexOf which you can use to implement getSongByTitle.

```
private final List<String> songList = new ArrayList<String>();

public int getSongByTitle(String title) {
    return songList.indexOf(title);
}
```

Comment: Plus one for simplicity

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like this function:

```
public int getSongByTitle(String title) {
  for(int i=0; i<this.songList.length; i++) {
   if (title.equals(this.songList[i])) // or what ever you want to compare
     return i;
  }
  // if you do not found any thing
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: You should use `equals()` method instead of `==` operator to test if *contents* of two `java.lang.String` are same.

Comment: Don't use `==` for string comparing. Use `title.equals(this.songList[i])`